# g++ error invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘info*’ [-fpermissive],error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-errors, g++, pthreads

i'm trying to parallelize the sum of Leibniz to approximate PI using pthreads. When i run this code with latest version of g++ these 2 errors appear and i really dont understand why, and i'm compiling like this:
g++ pi2.cpp -o pi2 -lpthread

```
error invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘info*’ [-fpermissive]

error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define top 1000000000

struct info
{
    int inicio;
    int fin;
    double pi;
};

int leibniz(void *ap2){
    struct info *ap;
    int start, end, i;
    ap = ap2;
    start = ap -> inicio;
    end = ap -> fin;

    double x = 0.0;
    double deno = 2*start + 1.0;
    double nume = 1.0;
    int diff = end - start;

    for (i = 0; i < diff; ++i)
    {
        x += nume/deno;
        deno += 2;
        nume = -nume;
    }
    ap -> pi = x*4.0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i, cont, rango;
    double pi;
    int numHilos = 2;
    char *check = "";

    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        numHilos = (int)strtol(argv[1], &check, 10);
        if (strcmp("", check) != 0)
        {
            printf("Entrada invalida\n");
        }
    }

    rango = top/numHilos;
    cont = 0;
    struct info array[numHilos];
    for (i = 0; i < numHilos; ++i)
    {
        array[i].inicio = cont;
        array[i].fin = rango;
        cont = rango;
        rango = rango + (top/numHilos);
    }

    pthread_t hilos[numHilos];
    int r, j, *retval;
    for (i = 0; i < numHilos; ++i)
    {
        r = pthread_create(&hilos[i], NULL, (void *)*leibniz, (void *)&array[i]);
        if (r != 0)
        {
            perror("Error al crear el hilo");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < numHilos; ++j)
    {
        r = pthread_join(hilos[j], (void **)&retval);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numHilos; ++i)
    {
        pi = pi + array[i].pi;
    }

    printf("pi: %2.12f \n", pi);
}
```

Comment: Unlike C, C++ will not allow you to simply assign `void *` to anything you want. You have to tell the compiler that you really mean it and that you aren't making a horrible mistake by casting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1: error invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘info*’

Unlike C, C++ will not allow you to simply assign `void *` to anything you want. You have to tell the compiler that you really mean it, and that you aren't making a horrible mistake by casting it.

So

```
ap = static_cast<info*>(ap2);
```

Error 2: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’

Exactly the same problem, but here it's easier. [`pthread_create` expects `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html), not `void *` so once you fix an even nastier bug you haven't seen yet, `int leibniz(void *ap2)` claims to return `int` but never does resulting in an ill formed program, all of the casting woes go away.

```
int leibniz(void *ap2)
```

becomes

```
void* leibniz(void *ap2)
```

and must return something. You don't care what, so place

```
return NULL;
```

at the end of the function.

`leibniz` now exactly matches `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`, so

```
r = pthread_create(&hilos[i], NULL, &leibniz, &array[i]);
```

Comment: it worked but with this change r = pthread_create(&hilos[i], NULL, &leibniz, &array[i]);

Comment: @RemedialGuns Durp. Will fix.

Comment: should be `void* leibniz(void*ap2)`

Comment: @RemedialGuns I think I'm still a little bit off. `leibniz` needs to return `void *`, not `void` Uhm, yeah. What he said.

Answer (score 0):

in tje beginning: `ap=ap2`->void* to info*

r=pthread_create(&hilos[i], NULL,  (void*)*leibniz,  &array[i])->void* to void(*)()

pthread_create get as 3rd parameter a pointer to a function.